# datagridview adding multiple records

Tags: c#, sql-server

i m trying to insert data into database using `datagridview`, i m using following code but it adding multiple records of single record any help will do

```
string connectionString = 
    "Data Source=S;Initial Catalog=Gits_Retailer;User ID=sa;Password=sa";

SqlConnection SqlConn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
SqlConn.Open();

DataSet ds = new DataSet();
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
{
    SqlDataAdapter da = 
        new SqlDataAdapter("INSERT INTO unit_master VALUES('" 
                            + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value 
                            + "')", SqlConn);    
    da.Fill(ds);                        
    SqlConn.Close()
}
```

Comment: now after u told me that my connection is closing inside for loop i close that connection outside the for loop but it still giving me the same result.suppose i add G unit first,then i close that form then again i open it and insert new value KG to DB,then result showed at datagridview is G Then KG and again G.

Comment: Can you Post your code fully that where you have used

Answer (score 0):

The first insert to DB would be successful but any subsequent would fail, you are closing the SqlConnection inside the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
string connectionString = 
        "Data Source=S;Initial Catalog=Gits_Retailer;User ID=sa;Password=sa";

    SqlConnection SqlConn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    SqlConn.Open();

    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
    {
        SqlDataAdapter da = 
            new SqlDataAdapter("INSERT INTO unit_master VALUES('" 
                                + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value 
                                + "')", SqlConn);    
        da.Fill(ds);                                
    }
SqlConn.Close()
```

Comment: @user3115080 Okay Post your Code Fully that where you used this method and tell clearly your problem

Comment: above is my full code for inserting data.when i tried to insert data ,each time that first inserted value getting multiplied by double.

Comment: @user3115080 Can you tell me your Gridview record count

Comment: k right now only 2 or 3 rows r inserted,but it will grow as more data will be inserted..

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
string connectionString = 
    "Data Source=S;Initial Catalog=Gits_Retailer;User ID=sa;Password=sa";

SqlConnection SqlConn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
SqlConn.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = SqlConn.CreateCommand();
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
{

    cmd.CommandText ="INSERT INTO unit_master VALUES('" 
                            + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value 
                            + "')";  
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

}
SqlConn.Close();
```

Comment: i tried above solution also but still same problem.first item get multiplied double after each entry abd same thing happening with newly inserted item.